# How do I stream from a single reader to multiple writers?

Tags: rust

I have a function like this:

```rust
pub fn build_tar(dir: Path) -> Result<(), String> {
  let file = File::create("archive.tar.br");
  let brotli = brotli::CompressorWriter::new(file);
  let archive = tar::Builder::new(brotli);

  for file in fs::read_dir(dir) {
    archive.append(file);
  }

  archive.finish();
}
```

(error handling omitted for brevity) Now I want to calculate a sha256 digest while building the archive, before compressing it. I have sha2::Sha256 which gives me a writer I can use to copy to, e.g. with io::copy. But now I need to duplicate data from archive to both this hash-writer and the compression-writer. I clumsily did something like this:

```rust
pub fn build_tar(dir: Path) -> Result<(), String> {
  let file = File::create("archive.tar.br");
  let brotli = brotli::CompressorWriter::new(file);
  let hash = sha2::Sha256::new();
  let archive1 = tar::Builder::new(brotli);
  let archive2 = tar::Builder::new(hash);

  for file in fs::read_dir(dir) {
    archive1.append(file);
    archive2.append(file);
  }

  archive1.finish();
  archive2.finish();
  HEXLOWER.encode(hash.finalize().as_ref())
}
```

Is this idiomatic? smart? Doesn't feel like it...

I tried googling for "tapping" a reader, or "duplicating" a reader, but couldn't find anything. I also browsed the doc pages of sha2 but can't figure out for the life of me, where the result of Sha256::new() implements the Write trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this very simple crate that does this: [io_tee](https://docs.rs/io_tee/). It's only a few hundred lines, with the following relevant parts for your situation.

```rs
pub struct TeeWriter<L, R> {
    left: L,
    right: R,
}

impl<L: Write, R: Write> Write for TeeWriter<L, R> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let n = self.left.write(&buf[..])?;
        self.right.write_all(&buf[..n])?;
        Ok(n)
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.left.flush()?;
        self.right.flush()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Then you can easily wrap your compression and hash streams into one `TeeWriter`.

```rs
let brotli = brotli::CompressorWriter::new(file);
let hash = sha2::Sha256::new();
// Create TeeWriter
let tee = TeeWriter::new(brotli, &mut hash);
let archive = tar::Builder::new(tee);
```

Comment: "Tee" was the keyword, thank you so much. I was dreading having to create something like this from scratch, but seeing a solution in <20 LoC is just beautiful.